# How to filter out LDAP results in osx

Tags: macos, ldap

when I use the command ldapwhoami it returns this:

```
SASL/GSSAPI authentication started
SASL username: snegoesc@42.FR
SASL SSF: 112
SASL data security layer installed.
dn:uid=snegoesc,ou=2017_paris,ou=2017,ou=paris,ou=people,dc=42,dc=fr
```

what I need to have is only this:

```
SASL/GSSAPI authentication started
SASL username: snegoesc@42.FR
SASL SSF: 112
SASL data security layer installed.
uid=snegoesc,ou=2017,ou=people,dc=42,dc=fr
```

so, my question is: how do I filter the results ?
I am putting this command in a .sh file, so if I can process the output using commands in the file and then display that, that's fine too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**With SED**

```
ldapwhoami | sed -E 's/^dn:uid=([^,]*),ou=[^,]*,ou=([^,]*),.*ou=people,dc=42,dc=fr/uid=\1,ou=\2,ou=people,dc=42,dc=fr/g'

SASL/GSSAPI authentication started
SASL username: snegoesc@42.FR
SASL SSF: 112
SASL data security layer installed.
uid=snegoesc,ou=2017,ou=people,dc=42,dc=fr
```

What it does :

`s/^dn:uid=([^,]*),ou=[^,]*,ou=([^,]*),.*ou=people,dc=42,dc=fr`

- `^dn:uid=` Match the start of the line : `dn:uid=`
- `([^,]*)` : Capture group everything till the next `,`
- `ou=[^,]*,` : Match any `ou=...`
- `ou=([^,]*)` : Capture group the next `ou=...`
- `.*ou=people,dc=42,dc=fr` : Match anything which finished by `ou=people,dc=42,dc=fr`

So the following line matches and captures : `snegoesc` and `2017` (the 2nd ou)
`dn:uid=snegoesc,ou=2017_paris,ou=2017,ou=paris,ou=people,dc=42,dc=fr`

And replaces it according to :

`uid=\1,ou=\2,ou=people,dc=42,dc=fr`

Meaning : `uid=<first capture group>,ou=<second capture group>,ou=people,dc=42,dc=fr`

**With AWK** (only tested on gnu linux, need to be adapted to macosx Awk implementation)

```
ldapwhoami | awk -F"," '$1~/^dn:/{print substr($1,4)","$3","$5","$6","$7; next}{print $0}'

SASL/GSSAPI authentication started
SASL username: snegoesc@42.FR
SASL SSF: 112
SASL data security layer installed.
uid=snegoesc,ou=2017,ou=people,dc=42,dc=fr
```

What it does :

- `-F","` : Set delimiter to `,`
- `$1~/^dn:/` : if first field of line matches `^dn:` (ie. line start with `dn:`) proceed to `{print substr($1,4)","$3","$5","$6","$7; next}` :

  - `print substr($1,4)","$3","$5","$6","$7` : print the subtring of the first field from char 4 to the end, then print fields 3, 5, 6, 7
  - `next` : proceed to next line without executing the following code
- `{print $0}` : Print line